# How to get Netcat to return unused ports

Tags: linux, sed, netcat

I tried this command to try to find unused ports. What I want it to do is run netcat on a range of ports, find the ones that are not running services, grep the first one of those lines of output, and then use sed to output the port number only.

```
nc -z <my url> 5000-5010 | grep -m 1 succeeded | sed 's/[^0-9]//g'
```

But when I try and launch a service using the port that is returned, I get a message saying the port is currently in use.

I found out netcat success means a service is running on the port, but when I try this instead

```
nc -zv <my url> 5000-5010 | grep -m 1 failed | sed 's/[^0-9]//g'
```

I get nothing, even though most lines of output contain the word failed.

Going through the man pages revealed that netcat -z only returns output for successful results, though why line after line of failed connection appears on my terminal window is still beyond me.

How can I use netcat to view the first port a connection failed on?

Comment: You may want to investigate [nmap](https://nmap.org/), which is a network scanning tool that would be probably make this task much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nc -v` command writes the failed/succeeded messages on standard error, not the standard output. You can redirect stderr to stdout using `2>&1`.

```
nc -zv <my url> 5000-5010 2>&1 | grep -m 1 failed
```

to get the failed line.

See http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/redirecting-stderr-to-stdout/

By the way, I suggest you use awk to get the port number from the output line:

```
nc -zv <my url> 5000-5010 2>&1 | grep -m 1 failed | awk '{print $6}'
```

which prints the value in the 6th column of the output line.

Answer (score 2):

To get a list of closed (unused) ports on a linux system you can use:

Realtime Output:

```
#!/bin/bash
remoteHost=stackoverflow.com
for i in {80..100}
do 
   nc -v -z -w 1 $remoteHost $i &> /dev/null && echo "Port $i Open" || echo "Port $i Closed" 
done
```

You can change the timeout, currently set to  1 sec (`-w 1`), to a higher value if needed.

---

Output:

```
Port 80 Open
Port 81 Closed
Port 82 Closed
Port 83 Closed
Port 84 Closed
Port 85 Closed
etc..
```

---

`nc` arguments:

`-v` Have nc give more verbose output.

`-z` Specifies that nc should just scan for listening daemons, without sending any data to them. It is an error to use this option in conjunction with the -l option.

`-w` timeout
If a connection and stdin are idle for more than timeout seconds, then the connection is silently closed. The -w flag has no effect on the -l option, i.e. nc will listen forever for a connection, with or without the -w flag. The default is no timeout.

---

Resources

[nc man](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nc)